# How to Edit Objects Independently in a Scene?

Tags: modeling, transforms, edit-mode, geometry

I'm new to Blender and decided to practice some of the basic skills I had learned in the video tutorial I am using.

I put a cylinder in the scene and scaled it with the idea of using it as a column. I save it.

I put a torus in the scene with the idea of scaling it and using it as the base for my column.

The torus, however, is linked to the column. I cannot figure out how to edit them separately. I have not made a parent child relationship with them although I plan to do that once I finish editing the base (the torus) and a third piece, a capital.

How can I edit these three pieces separately? I've tried working with the objects in Edit and Object modes.`

Thank you!

Sabi - a noobie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you've joined the two objects together as one. When adding an entirely new object, you should have selected 'create new object' instead of 'add object'.

However, in this case, your objects are linked as one. To separate them, go to edit mode, and select all the vertices that you want to separate as an entirely new object (your torus), use the command P and click 'selected'.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, Smiley! That's exactly what I did. Wow. Blender is indeed complex but I'll never forget this learning. You have answered my question very thoroughly. :-D

Comment: Newly added objects have been linked when I've inadvertently added a new object whilst still in Edit Mode.  Must get back into Object mode first.